# Can I order by GeneratedValue Entity Ids to get the last added entity

Tags: database, jakarta-ee, jpa

On every request to my SessionBean I need to receive the last added instance of a JPA entity whose PK is declared with `@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) Long id`.

My current approach is to add `ORDER BY e.id DESC` to the query. Unfortunately im not sure whether generated ids are strictly increasing for subsequently persisted entities and I can't seem to find any documentation on that topic. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA does not specify the order of id generation, so the provider is free to issue nonsequential ids.

If you want to rely on the entity insertion order, consider adding a temporal `createdAt` or `modifiedAt` field to your entity. This approach is used by some persistace frameworks, e.g. [ActiveRecord](https://rubygems.org/gems/activerecord).

You can leave the generation of this value to the provider by using a callback in a base entity class:

```
@PrePersist
void makeCreationTimestamp() {
 createdAt = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```